# Are really, really long passwords any more secure than short ones?

Tags: brute-force-attack

Just for fun, I want to encrypt a message that will take about 10 or so years to decrypt. My idea is to encrypt a message with AES-512 with a password one million decimal digits long.

Knowing not much about cryptography, is this any more difficult to decrypt than a shorter password? (I'm trying to prevent brute-forcing, until computing power becomes so high that it is irrelevant).

Comment: AES (in all variants) does not take a password, but a fixed-length key. You'll have to define how to derive the key from the password. Also, "decrypt" is normally used when one has the key, otherwise one used "break". Also, welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange.

Comment: See 2.1 on page 3 of $\:$ people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/lcs35-puzzle-description.txt . $\hspace{1.2 in}$

Comment: What is AES-512?

Comment: We should also note that 'very long passwords' tend to contain much less entropy than you might hope. For example, they are often based on famous phrases or quotes, and modern dictionary based attacks include these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no AES-512; AES takes keys of 128, 192 or 256 bits.

When encrypting with a password, there are two steps: first the password is converted into a key for the symmetric encryption, then the encryption is applied. Brute force can be applied either on the password (enumerating all possible passwords until a match is found) or on the key itself (enumerating all possible keys until a match is found).

A 128-bit key is [large enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6141/amount-of-simple-operations-that-is-safely-out-of-reach-for-all-humanity/6149#6149) to defeat brute force for long period of times. You can use a larger key for display purposes (larger figures impress managers, and some people apparently believe that key length correlates with manhood -- in the same way as big cars).

The same applies to a password with 128 bits of entropy -- which is a way of saying that there are 2<sup>128</sup> possible passwords, and you chose one at random among them. You can lower the entropy requirements on the password by using a [slow hashing process](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage/6415#6415); roughly speaking, if the function which converts the password into a key has the cost of 2<sup>20</sup> elementary encryption operations (that's about one million, and will be done in a fraction of a second with a basic PC) then you can be content with 108 bits of password entropy.

If your passwords are **random** sequences of alphanumeric characters (uppercase letters, lowercase letters, digits), then 19 characters are enough (because you use 62 distinct signs, and 62<sup>19</sup> is greater than 2<sup>108</sup>). More characters are useless. Note that "random" is an important word: I am *certainly not* talking about choosing the password with your head ! Human brains are definitely bad at randomness. Use a coin, dice, or a computer with `/dev/urandom`.

---

All of the above is about making sure that the message *will not* be decrypted within the next 10 years. A much harder problem is to also ensure that the message *will be* more or less easily decrypted in year 2022, but not before. I suggest entrusting the key to a notary, with instructions to reveal it at a specific future date.

Comment: My comment above (to the OP) is about an alternative approach to that much harder problem. $\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

Independent from deployed algorithm: The parameter space of a text string grows exponentially with the length and polynomially with the character set, i.e. roughly, length contributes more to security than special characters.

The class of algorithm you mention is not scalable and so cannot immediately be fed with arbitrary passwords. Usually you use a hash function, which maps a password to a hash-value of suitable length, which might serve as initialization vector for the encryption algorithm.

The entropy of your password can be measured by a hufman encoding based on the actual character set and the distribution of the characters.

When the entropy of your password is larger than that of the hash-value-space, you might split it accordingly to build a *set* of alternating initialization vectors.

In order to answer your question: With these measures security increases monotonously with the password entropy.

Answer (score 0):

According to Gibson Research's [Password Haystacks website](http://www.grc.com/haystack.htm) 23 digits would take 35 years at 100 trillion guesses per second.

Comment: Note: assuming a 64-character charset, 23 digits is overkill for AES-128 (it would take less time to brute-force the derived encryption key than the actual password). In this situation adding more digits is useless.

Comment: That's 'digits', that is, all characters in the password is a decimal digit ('0' - '9'); as above, if we allow a less restrictive character set, the time increases *significantly*

Comment: Gibson is an absolute fraud. You would be wise to avoid his services and "research".

Answer (score 0):

This may not focus directly on AES and is somewhat tangential, but currently there are debates as to the efficacy of large complex passwords, especially multiple ones.  People write them down.  This is compounded by automatic password expiry and password recycling rules.

Most IT guys have huge lists of passwords written down in books, spreadsheets and post-its.  What use AES 999 block BBC mode cipher   when the passwords are stored in a spreadsheet called PASSWORDS?

If you have a million character password, and you don't store it in some format what's the point?  You might as well just randomly scramble your message and have people reorder it.  And apart from tectonic or stellar movements, how do you intend to predict the future that far out or to access our processing capability in 10 years time?

Comment: Long password goes towards stream cipher.